# What's wrong with my setup for booting up a Beaglebone AI board?

Tags: boot, usb, debian, sd-card, beaglebone

So I'm trying to work with a Beaglebone AI microcontroller. I can't get it to boot up.

I've written the most recent image of the software to the micro SD card as described here: https://beagleboard.org/getting-started. I used Balena Etcher and it says it was successful. I tried both the second one under "Recommended Debian Images" as as well as the relevant one under ""Flasher" Debian Images" (https://beagleboard.org/latest-images).

Anyway, after that part, I connect a double-ended USB-A cord to the Beaglebone, and the other end to an adaptor that has USB-A at one end and USB-C at the other. The USB-C plugs into my Mac. It's my understanding that using the USB port will both power the board, and give it connectivity. However, my board has never showed the slightest indication of booting up (e.g., LED lights, heat...). I'm about at my wit's end; I've read everything on the internet I can find. I don't think I'm supposed to press any buttons on the board, like for Beaglebone Blacks or Greens, but I've tried that too.

Is it obvious to anyone what my issue could be? This is my first time trying, so I'm not sure how it usually goes. A lot of the Beaglebone documentation assumes a PC, and I don't know how that affects things besides that sometimes only the latest software image will work, but I think I've covered that. I don't have other SD cards to try right now. I'm willing to buy other equipment if I've gotten something wrong, but need some direction. Thank you!

Comment: If you have fixed you issue then post an answer rather than editing your question. If you want to delete your question [then you can](https://superuser.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question), but you are also allowed to [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to take the [tour] to see how things work here.

Answer (score 0):

So, first I realized iPhone chargers run 5V, which is the amount I needed; I plugged it into the wall with one and for the first time it booted up! Then, I tried plugging it into my laptop directly using a double-sided USB-C. That worked too. My conclusion is that most likely the original double sided USB-A cord just wasn't very good / not behaving up to spec. Indeed, Beaglebone cautions you in the instructions I linked: "If you provide your own, ensure it is of good quality."